# Why does my android ImageView grow in size after setting the width and height in xml?

Tags: android, imageview, position, android-imageview, image-resizing

I am trying to create an animation identical to the one in my iOS side so I converted the code to android however it appears it isn't as simple as that. I am guessing my problem is because android sizing differs (something to do with dp?). My animation depends on positions of the ImageView to know when to activate certain events in the animation.

**Output**

screenWidth = 720.0

screenHeight = 1184.0

bus width = 520

bus height = 154

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#87A877"
    tools:context=".MainMenu">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/street_image"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/streetImageView"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="41dp"
            android:layout_height="97dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stop_sign_image"
            android:paddingBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/stopSignImageView"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bench_image"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stopSignImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="146dp"
            android:id="@+id/benchImageView"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="268dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bus_with_front_door_closed"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/backBusImageView"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="31dp"
            android:background="@drawable/passenger_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/stopSignImageView"
            android:id="@+id/passengerImageView"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="268dp"
            android:layout_height="77dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bus_with_front_door_closed"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/frontBusImageView"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="23dp"
            android:background="@drawable/als_awareness_bus_ad"
            android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="194dp"
            android:id="@+id/busAdvertisementImageView"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**.java**

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity
{
    float screenWidth;
    float screenHeight;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        screenWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        screenHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        System.out.println("screenWidth = " + this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
        System.out.println("screenHeight = " + this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
        System.out.println("bus width = " + frontBusImageView.getWidth());
        System.out.println("bus height = " + frontBusImageView.getHeight());
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new AnimateBus(), 1, 7);
    }


    class AnimateBus extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    if(waitingForBus) // bus picking passenger up
                    {
                        if(busParkedInFrontOfStop)
                        {
                            if(passengerAtBusDoor)
                            {
                                if(busDoorsOpen)
                                {
                                    if(passengerOnBus)
                                    {
                                        if(busDoorsClosed)
                                        {
                                            if(passengerAtSeat)
                                            {
                                                if(passengerSittingDown) // start moving bus out of view with passenger on board
                                                {
                                                    if(frontBusImageView.getX() <= 300)
                                                    {
                                                        waitingForBus = false;
                                                        busParkedInFrontOfStop = false;
                                                        passengerAtBusDoor = false;
                                                        busDoorsOpen = false;
                                                        passengerOnBus = false;
                                                        busDoorsClosed = false;
                                                        passengerAtSeat = false;
                                                        passengerSittingDown = false;

                                                        backBusImageView.setX(screenWidth);
                                                        frontBusImageView.setX(screenWidth);
                                                        busAdvertisementImageView.setX(screenWidth); // +94

                                                        passengerImageView.setX(frontBusImageView.getX()+112);
                                                    }

                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        backBusImageView.setX(backBusImageView.getX()-1);
                                                        frontBusImageView.setX(frontBusImageView.getX()-1);
                                                        busAdvertisementImageView.setX(busAdvertisementImageView.getX()-1);
                                                        passengerImageView.setX(passengerImageView.getX()-1);
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                else // passenger sitting down
                                                {
                                                    if((screenHeight-passengerImageView.getY()) < 83)
                                                    {
                                                        if(standingOnBusStall-- < 1)
                                                            passengerSittingDown = true;
                                                    }

                                                    else
                                                        passengerImageView.setY(passengerImageView.getY()+1);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            else // get passenger to seat
                                            {
                                                if((passengerImageView.getX()-frontBusImageView.getX()) < 112)
                                                    passengerImageView.setX(passengerImageView.getX()+1);

                                                else
                                                    passengerAtSeat = true;
                                            }
                                        }

                                        else // close bus doors
                                        {

                                            backBusImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bus_with_front_door_closed);
                                            busDoorsClosed = true;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    else // passenger stepping onto bus
                                    {
                                        if((screenHeight-passengerImageView.getY()) > 88)
                                        {
                                            if(standingOnBusStall++ > 100)
                                                passengerOnBus = true;
                                        }

                                        else
                                            passengerImageView.setY(passengerImageView.getY()-1);
                                    }
                                }

                                else // open bus door
                                {
                                    frontBusImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bus_with_front_door_opened);
                                    backBusImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bus_with_front_door_opened);
                                    busDoorsOpen = true;
                                }
                            }

                            else // passenger walking to bus door
                            {
                                passengerImageView.setX(passengerImageView.getX()-1);

                                if(passengerImageView.getX() < 53)
                                    passengerAtBusDoor = true;
                            }
                        }

                        else // bus driving in front of stop
                        {
                            backBusImageView.setX(backBusImageView.getX()-1);
                            frontBusImageView.setX(frontBusImageView.getX()-1);
                            busAdvertisementImageView.setX(busAdvertisementImageView.getX()-1);

                            if(frontBusImageView.getX() < 36)
                                busParkedInFrontOfStop = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image is being scaled and resized to fit your layout properly.

You can change this how you like, using the [android:scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) attribute in your layout.

http://javatechig.com/android/android-imageview-example.

Comment: CENTER is the only type that appears to not rescale the imageview. However I don't want to centre it in the view like it says it does, so I am kind of confused which type to use.